# What is the equivalent of chr(153) (The TM SYMBOL) in Unicode

Tags: delphi, unicode, ascii

In earlier Delphi versions, I could use

```
s:=chr(153);
```

to get a trademark symbol in a string.  In Delphi 2010, that doesn't work any longer, perhaps to do with unicode.  What is the equivalent code string to put the TM symbol into my string?

Comment: Ever heard of charmap.exe? Press Win+R, write "charmap.exe", press Enter, select a decent Unicode font (e.g. Arial Unicode MS or Lucida Sans Unicode or, in this case, even Tahoma), select Advanced mode, make sure the character set is Unicode, and search for "trade mark".

Comment: By the way: what does this have to do with ASCII? There is only 128 ASCII characters, named 0, 1, ..., 127. You probably mean ANSI, or Windows-1252.

Comment: What's wrong with just using it as a literal? `s:='™';`?

Comment: @Michael: that will only work if your sourcecode is saved as a file that is encoded in a unicode form. If your sourcecode is not, than what the user sees totally depends on the encoding of the file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that `chr(153)` is "Ö" ([Code page 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)), oh wait, it is "r" ([EBCDIC 037](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC_037)).

Actually `chr(153)` is undefined unless you also specify the code page you are using.
Which is exactly the reason you should use [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode).

Wikipedia has pages for most [Unicode symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_symbols), and includes the Unicode [codepoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codepoint) for them.

There is the plain [trademark symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trademark_symbol) having unicode codepoint U+2122 (Delphi: `Chr($2122)` or `#$2122`).
There is also the [registered trademark symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_trademark_symbol) having unicode codepoint U+00AE (Delphi: `Chr($00AE)` or `#$00AE`).

The [unicode site](http://www.unicode.org/) has a [list of charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) where you can find all symbols, but it takes time getting used how to find them (as the number of charts is a bit large).
The plain trademark symbol is part of the [letterlike symbols](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2100.pdf).
The registered trademark symbol is part of the [latin-1 supplement](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf).

--jeroen

Comment: I also would make a case for the unicode book. I once fetched the Unicode 4.0 book from a bargain bin, and it is a great weapon :-) It can also be used as a fine reference btw.

Answer (score 11):

In D2010, I can do this:

```
s := '™' + chr(8482) + #8482;  // yields 3 subsequent TM symbols
```

Result:  ™™™

Here's a good article, by Joel himself - I re-read it just today, in fact.
http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 3):

As per the [Unicode code chart for "letterlike symbols"](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2100.pdf), the TM symbol is Unicode U+2122. I don't know enough Delphi to know how you turn that into a character - perhaps

```
s := chr(8482);
```

? (8482 is the decimal for hex 2122.)

Alternatively, having looked at [this page](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38693), you might try:

```
s := #$2122;
```

Comment: In Delphi, it would be #$2122  -- the # sign indicates a character, and the $ makes it a hex number.

Answer (score 1):

It's character U+2122 (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2122/index.htm). I haven't used Delphi for a long time, but before anything else you should try to enter the character directly (probably using a Character Map utility like Windows's charmap.exe or BabelMap). That's easier to read than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

To discover the Unicode codepoint for a given character, open Accessories -> System Tools -> Character Map, select a Unicode font, look for the character you need, in the lower left corner the application displays the Unicode code.

Answer (score -1):

in html its &#x2122 try using it on http://code.cside.com/3rdpage/us/unicode/converter.html